# Judgment in testing anticipation effect in Diff-in-Diff?

Tags: difference-in-difference

Regarding **Difference-in-Difference**, there is one important assumption of concern is **"no anticipation effect"**.
I read the paper of [Borusyak, 2021](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12419.pdf) and I saw that **he identified it in the Assumption 2** (page 8).

After running the test, I have the result is as below ( in this case I shift the actual event year to 3 years before.

[image]

**tau0 represents the average estimate for relative year = -3, tau1 relative toyear = -2, ..., tau3 for relative year = 0**

**I do not know how to explain this result properly about whether the anticipation effect exists?** Should we use the joint null test for tau0, tau1, and tau2?

Comment: I think one approach is to shift to when the policy is announced or starts looking likely to happen and then do a joint test like you proposed.

Comment: @dimitriy . Thank you for your encouragement, but I think I need a reference for the joint null test like that.

Comment: Take a look at the pdf documentation for Stata’s estat granger command. I don’t really know of a more authoritative reference.